# Android Listview user interaction design context menu on click or longpress

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I have a listview which shows items in rows. Each row has a checkbox which will select the item in row.

There are some actions ActionList = { Action1, Action2,...} which can be performed on any item. I plan to show a contextual popup menu which lists all the actions which can be done on the particular item

There is a very common Action1 which I would like to put on the bottom of screen as a big button. User can just tap and select the checkbox and press the bottom button to perform Action1.

Now as android users are accustomed with tap on the entire row of listview to check the item. I am left with just LongPress to show my context popup menu.

I am left with choices

(a) Continue with what I have

(b) Split the tap into 2 parts, if user taps on the area around actual checkbox ( 40% right part of screen) the box would be checked and the bottom Action1 Button can be pressed to perform the action on selected group

If the user taps on area around left 60% area. I show a context menu.

(c) Show a option button along with chkbox [ ] (*) and show the context popup menu when user clicks the (*)

Any ideas guys...

Answer (score 0):

B sounds good. Just make sure that 40% of the screen (around checkbox) has different shading, so that it's visible to the user.